# Redirect component seems not working with trailing slash in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this implementation to redirect */blog* and */blog/* to some working url

```
   <Redirect from="blog" to="http://somedomain/blog/" />
   <Redirect from="blog/" to="http://somedomain/blog/" />
```

It looks like /blog is redirected successfully, but /blog/ looks not working.

May I know how do I make /blog/ still working at this case

Package.json: "react-router": "^0.13.5"

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router` 0.13.x the `Redirect` component takes a name of another route and not a URL, which is why your redirect isn't working.

In `react-router` 0.14 or above `Redirect` can take either name of a Route or the path of said Route.

0.13.x: For a given route

```
<Route name="blog" path="blog/" handler={BlogHandler} />
```

the Redirect Component will have to be

```
<Redirect from="blog" to="http://somedomain/blog/" />
```

1.0.x:

```
<Route name="blog" path="blog/" component={BlogComponent} />
<Redirect from="blog/" ...>
or
<Redirect from="blog" ...>
```

Both works.

Comment: I give it a try. It seems `from` is taking URL instead of Route name. Which version are u using ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont think it is correct. even I am using 0.13.5 , the `from` in Redirect component is using `path` instead of `router name`. also, it doesnt explain why `blog` is working but `blog/` is not working. This redirect component looks weird to me